# How to execute and sandbox Ruby code snippets from within Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, cloud, sandbox

I want to execute Ruby code snippets from within a service I built.
The issue I'm facing is sandboxing the running snipets.

As the easiest way I found is using `ruby script.rb` or using `eval`.

I'm willing to use a different language or read any related books to do it and will be thankful for providing any related tutorials or books.

Comment: AFAIK Ruby does not have sandboxing built-in. You need to start another instance of the VM as you are doing with `ruby script.rb`. `eval` doesn't cut it because that code can modify global state e.g. redefine built-in classes and methods.

Comment: What are the languages that have built-in sandboxing?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any language that has it (I've never heard of such a thing). I would recommend trying out generic sandboxing tools and running Ruby with those. Alternatively you could build your own Ruby sandbox using the [C API](http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guide. I'll give it a try and keep this question updated.